# How often can you produce cuttings from mint?

Tags: propagation, cuttings, mint

If I create a cutting from my mint plant and begin to grow it in a container, about how long after it gets established should I wait before I create another cutting?  What is the minimum waiting period after the roots begin to become established that a cutting can be made without harming the health of the plant?

Assume that I am trying to create as many mint plants as fast as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When taking cuttings from a plant, I try not to take more than 1/3 of the current healthy growth.  For some plants, you shouldn't take even that much.  As has been mentioned, mint is very prolific and a fast grower, so you should be just fine taking around 1/3 of the currently growing, healthy young branches each time you cut.

Also, mint can be propagated from the roots.  After your plant has become well established, remove it from its pot and look for thick, pale root-like stems lying just under the soil surface. Many of these will have growing tips already starting to come out of the jointed areas.  Carefully cut a few of these roots from the mother plant, then cut them into 2-4  inch pieces, and place them horizontally just under the surface of a flat or pot of moist soil. Give them a bit of time to send out new growth before transplanting them into their own pots.  Most of them should "take" and this will enable you to get your mint propagated out just a bit faster.

Comment: I can confirm that the 'root' method works very well. Mint is rampant and will grow these stems all the time, and they will "take" even if you don't want them to. :-) I can imagine the sprouts will grow faster if you keep them attached to the mother plant for a while. The new plants can grow more leaves and roots while being fed from the mother plant. That works well for strawberries, but I haven't experimented in detail with mint.

Answer (score 3):

It should be safe when there is new growth from the cutting you planted.  Wait for a new shoot to get large enough to transplant.  Mint is a very prolific grower.